# Require support in ruby on rails smtp delivery method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Im trying to send a notification email to my account in gmail by using smtp delivery method when i click the place order button but i am getting all sorts of connection and authentication errors

like these:`An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect`

```
Net::ReadTimeout when calling ActionMailer

rails email error - 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. 

SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
```

i have searched everywhere and everytime i try to change the port or do anything to my developments.rb file either of these errors shows up

this is my development.rb file

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  # config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries=true
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors=true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method= :smtp
     config.action_mailer.smtp_settings={
     :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] ,#your gmail id
    :password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"], #your gmail password
    :authentication       => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
         tls: true
        }

end
```

i dont know what the hell is going on i need some help in this and currently i am getting the first error that existing connection one

Comment: Does your environment has `GMAIL_USERNAME` and password variables set?

Comment: i dont know i just followed a tutorial and it was working there, and when i searched on google some people didnt even use then ENV[] ,so could you tell me how can i set them cause im really confused

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the thing. You need to set your gmail account username and password value. If you're testing locally, you might simply replace these with the string values of your user/pass: `ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]` and `ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]`.